# how to define a function with two parameters but also be able to run with only 1 parameters?

Tags: python

so today i was wandering on codewars and found this kata:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/51646de80fd67f442c000013/train/python
the problem itself seems to be quite easy, but as you can see (in the link):

```
stripUrlParams('www.codewars.com?a=1&b=2&a=2')
stripUrlParams('www.codewars.com?a=1&b=2&a=2', ['b'])
```

the first line is the function with only 1 parameter but the second is a function with two parameters, is that even possible to create such function?

Comment: This question is a bit vague. What do you want to happen when the first parameter *isn't* provided?

Answer (score 2):

you can set a parameter to have a default value.

```
def example(a , b=3):
    return (a+b)
```

now b will be 3 unless stated otherwise:

```
print example(1)
#>>> 4
print example(1,b=4)
#>>> 5    or
print example(1, 4)
#>>> 5
```

Comment: thank you very much, i didnt know about it.

Comment: Happy to show you! :)

Comment: in addtion to your solution, the way you write it can cause some unexpected output (i tried and... well it was unexpected :))) )

Comment: What did you expect and what result was unexpected?